# Access Database Update

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have a `datagridview` that wont update when button is pressed.

It displays access database table content.

button code:

```
private void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update the stock level?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.hPTableAdapter.Update(inkDataSet.HP);
            inkGridView.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
    }
```

And the string for the update in the hPTableAdapter:

```
UPDATE HP
SET Black = ?, Cyan = ?, Magenta = ?, Yellow = ?
```

No error is shown, appears to work until closing the application and rerunning in Visual Studio 2015.

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ink
{
    public partial class inkForm : Form
    {

        public inkForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int itemrow = -1;
            String searchValue = searchtextBox.Text.ToUpper();

            if (searchValue != null && searchValue != "")
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in inkGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                    {
                        itemrow = row.Index;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue) && itemrow == -1)
                    {
                        itemrow = row.Index;
                    }
                }
                if (itemrow == -1)
                {
                    searchtextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchtextBox.BackColor = Color.White;
                    inkGridView.Rows[itemrow].Selected = true;
                    inkGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = itemrow;
                }
            }
        }

        private void inkForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.hPTableAdapter.Fill(this.inkDataSet.HP);

        }

        private void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update the stock level?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.hPTableAdapter.Update(inkDataSet.HP);
                inkGridView.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
            }
        }

        private void inkGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? do you get an error? Does the database log record an error? What happens?

Comment: Just update, it goes through the popups as normal, no errors shown.

Comment: What do you mean by 'appears to work' and then doesn't? Also, can you show us all the code? You're missing some if your goal is to update an Access Database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No errors show when updating, it pops up to say it has updated the record.  Then when it application is closed and reopened, the changes not there.  Updated with full code.

Comment: You're actually missing the code that connects to the database; that's why it isn't working. You're updating the `DataAdapter` in memory, but never connecting to the database.  Check the example on that link I sent you; You need to connect to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fit this into the current code, OleDbDataAdapter is not found?

Comment: The code was not missing, the connection string needed the full length path to the database.

Comment: So where in your question is your connection string? I don't see it at all. Any of it.

Comment: In the project properties.  You are aware you can do it like that?

Comment: The reason I say that is because in order for us to help you, we need *all* relevant code. Your connection string is relevant.  It's also in your `web.config` or `app.config` and as such should have been here; or an MVCE that includes a connection string that reproduces the problem you're having.  That's why it's important, without all that information, your question isn't useful to future visitors that have the same problem. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full length path to database required in connection string.

Comment: Unless you put your original connection string in the question; and the updated connection string here, there's no way for a future visitor visiting this question to know what the answer is, or what the problem even looked like. The close reason I used originally (and the reason it's on hold now) is because we need an MCVE; a minimal *complete* verifiable example. The 'complete' part is what's missing.